# how to model the Map in swagger

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui

```
public class Response
{
    private List<Hotel> HotelMap

}

public class Hotel
{

private String name;
private String id;
private Map<String, RoomType> roomTypeMap;

}
```

How to annotate this Map in Hotel Class to be shown in swagger UI model and Model Schema using java swagger annotation.

I tried to diffrent @ApiModelProperty didnt work.please help